# How to get id of the clicked element in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

Hopefully, I can make this clear. I have the following JSON array:

```js
[
  {
    "firstname": "123",
    "lastname": "321",
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

So when I click on certain element I want to get the id of that element. I'm struggling how to do that.

I know that this should be done with fetch method and in the parameter I need to specify the id. Here is my thought:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3004/posts'+id, {  

      method: 'GET', 
     
      body: JSON.stringify(newID),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
```

But how can I get id of the clicked element? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does getting the id of an element have to do with fetch? Getting data from the server and getting it from the DOM are *very* different operations.

Comment: I just want to get certain element and edit it in the database

Comment: What do you mean by 'element' here? Element is a technical term in React that means an HTML element in the DOM. That's not the sort of thing you edit in a database.

Comment: Normally you'd have a click handler that takes an ID, e.g., `onClick: () => doTheThing(obj.id)` as each object is rendered. There are other ways; this is the most obvious. I don't see any JSX code, though, so no idea what makes the most sense in your app.

Comment: I mean that I have key value pair in database {"id": id }

So how can I get this id?

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda spoon-feed, but I think this is the code you wanted:

```
export default function App() {
  const arr = [
    {
      firstname: "123",
      lastname: "321",
      id: 1
    }
  ];

  const getArrId = async (id) => {
    console.log(id); // we can access id now
    const res = await fetch(); 
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* access each item's id in an array*/}
      {arr.map((i) => ( // access each item with i
        <div key={i.id}> // gotta provide key for react to diff each element
          <div>{i.firstname}</div>
          <button onClick={() => getArrId(i.id)}>get id</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Explanation: since your data is an array, all we have to do is map out the data, and access each individual item, `i` represent each item(object, in your case) in the array, and therefore we can access each item's id, and supply it in onClick handler `onClick={() => getArrId(i.id)}`

BTW, be sure to check out [List rendering in react](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists), and [sandbox to play around](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-elion-1359kk?file=/src/App.js)